# How to conduct DDoS attack practically?

Tags: attacks, ddos, denial-of-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate DDoS attacks from the Internet?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/how-to-simulate-ddos-attacks-from-the-internet)

I want to conduct a DDoS attack. Can anyone please tell how can i conduct it? What are the latest DDos attacks? What are the tools available for it?. I dont want to conduct any real time attack but as a part of my academics i have to show demo of it. So it would be helpful to me if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

One has many possibilities to DDoS. I can't think of any tools that work with a click of a button.

Some possibilities:

1. Network congestion (just limit a server upstream to 10 Mbit and set up 10 clients that each download at 100 mbit)
2. Request fload for a webserver (You can use apachebenchmark for this on different clients)
3. TCP SYN flood (just write a simple script that opens TCP connections but never replies to the server's SYN/ACK, multi thread it)
4. ICMP flood (multi threaded script on lots of clients that ping your demoserver)

Another idea for a simulation might be (my friends did this one last year as a project):

- Use a demo-machine with a vulnerable version of proftpd to rootkit a guest machine and install [kaiten.c](http://packetstormsecurity.org/irc/kaiten.c) on it (u will need multiple guests though)
- Let them join an IRC channel so you can send commands (botnet)
- let them all start executing one of the previously discussed scripts

Comment: can you please give more insight into the second option ? If any link is there for it then it will also be fine.

Comment: Added the kaiten.c link,I hope you are not just looking for a click and ddos application :p

Comment: Definitely i am not expecting that. Anyways thanks for reply. Let me try this solution..

Comment: @Lucan Kauffman: is there any other alternative to IRC channels for using kaitan.c to conduct DDoS?

Comment: If you write it yourself there can be.

Answer (score 0):

Since your purposes here are strictly academic, you probably don't need to generate an overwhelming amount of traffic - just enough to demonstrate a grasp of the concept. With that said, I'd do two things:

1. Download the following: http://sourceforge.net/projects/loic/ It's the tool that's most likely to be used for this kind of attack "in the wild", so you might as well use it.
2. Install the same on whatever trash hardware you've got laying around. You really just enough hardware to make a noise on the network, so you're not going to need high-spec machines for this.

Note that these instances can be coordinated via IRC as Lucas Kauffman suggested (I think that feature is called "Hivemind" or something), if you want to go that far. Otherwise, just manually point them at your target and let 'em rip.